# Extract string after pattern to unknown stop point

Tags: r, string, text-extraction

In a dataframe I have a column named *buckets* that contains rows that fit the following pattern:

{"21-45":**1**,"541-600":2,"46-60":2,"721-840":2,"1201-1320":1}

{"21-45":**7**,"481-540":10,"541-600":6,"46-60":2,"721-840":2}

{"481-540":1,"301-360":1,"<20":2,"61-120":1,"21-45":**10**}

{"481-540":1,"21-45":**200**,"721-840":1,"<20":3,"61-120":2}

I wish to extract the number that follows the pattern **"21-45":**

So I would be left with:

1

7

10

200

The pattern **"21-45":** can appear anywhere in the string and the number of digits following it vary and may end in a "," or in a "}".

The dataframe is very large, so I would like to accomplish this as parsimoniously as possible.  I have no idea what the best way is to approach this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(str1, '(?<=21-45":)\\d+'))
#[1]   1   7  10 200
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("{\"21-45\":1,\"541-600\":2,\"46-60\":2,\"721-840\":2,\"1201-1320\":1}", 
"{\"21-45\":7,\"481-540\":10,\"541-600\":6,\"46-60\":2,\"721-840\":2}", 
"{\"481-540\":1,\"301-360\":1,\"<20\":2,\"61-120\":1,\"21-45\":10}", 
"{\"481-540\":1,\"21-45\":200,\"721-840\":1,\"<20\":3,\"61-120\":2}"
)
```

Comment: Victory!  Thank you very much.